# LINQ TO XML get node based on multiple conditions

Tags: xml, linq

How can i get the node "FieldName" based on xID && dID through LINQ TO XML. 
Note : dID may or may not exist.
What i had tried so far is printed below. 
However my code does not handle the condition when dID doesn not exist

```
<Configuration>
        <Contract xID="2">
            <Document dID="227">
                <FieldName name="AAAA"/>
                <FieldName name="BBBB"/>
            </Document>
        </Contract>
        <Contract xID="5">

                <FieldName nam`enter code here`e="CCCC"/>
                <FieldName name="DDDD"/>

        </Contract>
    </Configuration>
```

What i had tried so far is printed below. 
However my code does not handle the condition when dID doesn not exist

```
    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("../../FieldConfiguration.xml");

    var fieldNames = (from n in xmlDoc.Descendants("Contract")
                      where (int)n.Attribute("xID") == 5 &&
                            (int)n.Element("Document").Attribute("dID") == 227
                      from f in n.Element("Document").Elements()
                      select (string) f.Attribute("name")).ToList();

    foreach (string name in fieldNames)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Site: " + name);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a check for null in your where clause

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("../../FieldConfiguration.xml");

    var fieldNames = (from n in xmlDoc.Descendants("Contract")
                      where (int)n.Attribute("xID") == 5 &&
                            n.Element("Document").Attribute("dID") != null && 
(int)n.Element("Document").Attribute("dID") == 227
                          from f in n.Element("Document").Elements()
                          select (string) f.Attribute("name")).ToList();

    foreach (string name in fieldNames)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Site: " + name);
    }
```

Comment: Jason: IF my inputs are xID= 5 and dID = 777 than in that case my result set should contain "CCCC" & "DDDD" it should  ignore the dID

Comment: you can add as many checks as you like in the where clause, use parentheses to dictate precedence

Comment: I am new in LINQ TO XML, so i am not able to ignore the "dID" if its not thr in "Contract" node